# Logic app turn the binary to bad character

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I created a logic app which gets the data from restapi. The content type of data is Application/protobuf(protobuf is a binary data made by google https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/tutorials) I know that LA uses base64 encoding so it changes the data to base64 encoding. As the data to be deserialised via protoc complier so it needed binary format. So i store this data into a variable and trying to paas this further processing. But unfortunately the data stores in variable changes into boxes and ? So protoc compiler fails to deserialised the same.
I tried base64tobinary and http() as per suggestion mentioned section "other content type" on microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type#applicationxml-and-applica...
But it did not work. Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the issue and found that the rest API body which we are receiving will be transformed back to string when we use `string()` i.e.. `string(triggerBody())` dynamic expression.

Later, I convert to binary by using the dynamic expression 'binary', i.e. 'binary(outputs('Compose')', which will return a 'application/octet-stream' result. When I tried to convert back to a string, everything worked great for me.

Here is the flow of my logic app

[image]

and here is the output

[image][image]

Comment: I tried this however it did not work for me. The character moved into boxes and when i tried to deserialized it, the protoc compiler throws an error.

Comment: @Harsh Can you provide more information on the data that you are sending? Would be more helpful if you provide an example of that data.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the way of using. Instead of streaming, I am storing the data into file and processing further.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).